# Dynamic dictionary feature in NMT V3

Tags: microsoft-translator, neural-mt

I have heard that it should be possible to add a dynamic dictionary, holding a set of terms or word list when you train your model. This should be possible in the Translation Hob today.

How to do this using V3 or NMT in portal.customtranslator.azure.ai using custom translator project?

/Mats

Answer (score 0):

At this time the dictionary feature is not available in the NMT custom translator but it is a feature we are working on and will release in a future update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea of when this will be released?

Comment: We can't really give a release date at this time, but it is a feature that many people have requested, so it is a priority.

Comment: Is this feature released yet ?